# Concatenating a string and passing as a parameter?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I wrote my own logger that I can use as follows:

```
LOG("This is the number five: " << 5 << ".");
```

I'd like to write an error checking method that simply takes a return code, checks if it's an error, and if so prints an error message

Thus, I'd like to turn:

```
if(result == -1)
{
    LOG("ERROR! We got a result of: " << result << ".");
    // Do some other stuff
}
```

into:

```
checkForError(result, "ERROR! We got a result of: " << result << ".");

void checkForError(int result, SomeStringType message)
{
    if(result == -1)
    {
    LOG(message);
    // Do some other stuff
    } 
}
```

is this possible? I've tried passing it as a char*, a std:string, and as a stringstream, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly

Is there any way to do this so I'm simply concatenating the error message in the call to the function?

Comment: Have you considered `ostringstream`?

Comment: #define LOG_ON_FAIL(result, prompt) if(-1 == result) {LOG((prompt)<<(result))}

Comment: Character literals never would accept `"ERROR! We got a result of: " << result << "."`  (`operator<<`) operations well.That's not how you get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You could do it like this:

```
#define LOG(X)                                   \
        do {                                     \
            std::ostringstream log_stream;       \
            log_stream << X;                     \
            LOG::log_internal(log_stream.str()); \
        } while (0)
```

where `LOG::log_internal` might be declared in your logger header like

```
struct LOG {
    static void log_internal(const std::string &);
};
```

The main drawback of this is that it's not the most hygienic macro ever -- if the argument `X` contains semicolons, then you could have additional statements executed inside the macro's scope, and there won't be a compiler error. This macro is far from cryptic though in my opinion, and fortunately you don't actually have to worry about an attacker performing SQL-injection-esque attacks against your macros.

I use loggers that basically look like this in my projects, and I learned to do it this way from other projects. (Actually the one I use is a little more developed, it also passes `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to the `LOG::log_internal` function, and there's log channels and log levels which may or may not be active etc. etc...)